# Separation of sugar and fat in a column chromatography

Tags: organic-chemistry, chromatography, medicinal-chemistry

I am chemist at organic and bioorganic chemistry,I want to know if we are separating sugar and fat in a column chromatography who will be down first ? and why ?

Thank you.

Comment: Column chromatography is unlikely to be the correct method for separation here.

Comment: Homework .... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugars are polar, fats are not. Thus if the mobile phase is polar and stationary phase isn't - then sugars will come out first. Otherwise (in case of reverse-phase chromatography) fats will come out first while sugars will be held by stationary phase.